# innerHTML disappearing quickly from div in jQuery load file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

innerHTML appears then quickly disappears in under a second, div in a jquery load file.

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#page1').click(function () {
        $('#page-content-wrapper').load('page1.html');
        document.getElementById("changeme").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
    })
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/site.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TimeApp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="page1">Page 1</span></a> <a id="page2">Page 2</span></a>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <!-- Page content is loaded here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
<div id="changeme"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `load()` makes an AJAX request to retrieve the content from page1.html. While this is happening you update the `innerHTML` of the element within the `#page-content-wrapper`. When the AJAX request completes, the content of page1.html *overwrites* the existing content - which you just updated.

To fix the problem put the line which updates the text of the element in the callback of `load()`, so that it's only ever executed *after* the AJAX request:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#page1').click(function() {
    $('#page-content-wrapper').load('page1.html', () => {
      $("#changeme").text("Paragraph changed!");
    });
  });
});
```

Better still, put the content you need in to page1.html directly, to avoid this unnecessary code.